# Trying to Parse a text file in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, batch-file, text

I am trying to find a way for c# to parse a text(bat, txt) and to be able to grab information from the file by line. 
for example the file would be like this:

```
About
Menu
Staff
Contact
```

basically i want to grab that information and use it else in the program but to keep this easy to edit for other people in the office without mucking about the actual code.

I'm pretty new to C#, I've done similar applications in C++, but i am not sure how i would port that over to c#.
Thanks

Comment: System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()

Comment: Well what *specifically* are you trying to achieve, and what have you already tried? A search for "reading a text file in c#" gives plenty of hits, including ones on MSDN. It's a good idea to at least have a go at a problem before asking a question here.

Comment: thanks john, I have tried the one on MSDN, but i didn't get very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file you can easily use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it will return a string array that contains each line of your file.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filepath");
```

Then you can use/manipulate these lines however you like.

Comment: Thanks i think this will work Great